# Php API Nuki doorlock Post

Tags: php, api

I am a very beginner at PHP and need to unlock a Nuki from a webpage.
I've generated an api, I have a bearer token etc and apache running on my computer.

When I run the command from my commandline everything is working but nothing is happening when I try it like this... Did I miss something?

```
 <?php

$url = "https://api.nuki.io/smartlock/HIDDEN/action/unlock";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
   "Accept: application/json",
   "Authorization: Bearer {HIDDEN}",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);

?>
```

Btw: the working Curl (commandline) is this:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer HIDDEN' 'https://api.nuki.io/smartlock/HIDDEN/action/unlock'
```

Comment: Hi. What does your `var_dump($res)` actually output? Also, the PHP code calls `/unlock`  while the CLI version calls `/lock`. Have you tried both in both environments?

Comment: Ok I've edited the CLI version. I have two versions (lock / unlock) and switched them.

I honestly don't know what the var_dump outputs? How can I check this?

Comment: Ah, the CLI version also uses `POST`, so try adding `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);`. cURL will do a GET as default.

Comment: Added the POST, still nothing is happening at the lock when I try this..

Comment: So what does `var_dump($res);` actually output? What is the actual response from the API? You can also use [curl_getinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) with different flags to get more information about the response, like status code etc. The more you/we know about the response, the easier it will be to debug.

Comment: It seems like everything was already working fine... I used the file:///C:/xampp/htdocs url to open my file. I now use the localhost and everything is working fine!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, if you want to call a PHP script through a browser, you need to call it through a web server with PHP support. Browsers can't execute PHP (since it's a server side language)